# Callback to a Webhook, can be tested in Karate

Tags: webhooks, karate

I have scenario to test, in the request we can pass callback url (which will be webhook) and its a aysnc response so I will get acknowledgement 1st and actual response will be send to Call back url/Webhook.

Is it possible to test such scenario in Karate?
How to create a webhook url which can listen?
Is it possible to test real-time, with out mock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No absolutely not possible without a mock - for example one that you start locally or a common / central one that you know the location of.

If you start one locally, you can poll it to see if a callback was received. Search the docs for "polling". There may be better ways to "connect" the mock to your main test, but you need to be clear about Karate Java interop and how to use mocks.

And you probably need to ensure that you know what hostname etc. to pass. This sounds like a complicated test, which requires you to learn and apply multiple Karate concepts. I suggest you start by reading this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#consumer-provider-example

My suggestion is unless this is a very critical flow - just test half of it - and move on to some other work. Automating it may not be worth it.

EDIT: please refer to this example which has all the pieces you need to be able to write the kinds of tests you want: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1417023536082812935

Comment: thanks  Peter. We have 2 separate flows, one was implemented with polling. Another one callback case, I will try with Mock concept.

Comment: @sajithchandran an update - please see this example: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1417023536082812935

Comment: @sajithchandran was your callback issue resolved?