# How to use Karate to test receive webhook and process webhook

Tags: karate

System A API server ( Implemented in Go ) -> POST HTTP CALL to Mock Server B ( implemented in Go ) 
Mock Server B sends webhook -> System A Webhook Consumer (Implemented in Go) 
System A Webhook Consumer processes webhook and updates postgres DB to update user-state lets say from inactive to active.

How should I use Karate to effectively test such an asynchronous flow without the benefit of interoperability with Java. All the services are deployed on GCP cloud for integration testing

Should I implement a waitTime in karate script after making POST HTTP Call to Mock Server B and poll System A GET API to check for updates on the postgres DB such as GET user-state.json to check if state is active?

I could only think of polling mechanism but i am not sure if is good practice with karate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now the best reference is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68037401/143475

Since this is a common need, we are releasing dedicated webhook support as part of the [async addons](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-addons/blob/main/README.md) (not open-source) in January 2024. If you are interested in beta-testing, [let us know](https://www.karatelabs.io/contact-us).